# Azure AD B2C Graph API 401 Unauthorized

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to do an Azure AD Graph API REST API call to get the currently logged in user information. However, the HTTP GET call to https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6 fails always with the response **401 Unauthorized**. I have registered an App in Azure AD and have the below API Permissions configured:

[image]

The call to authorize endpoint is shown below:

> HTTP GET https://{my tenant}.b2clogin.com/{my
>   tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_signinsignup&client_id={my
>   app
>   id}&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44351/Login/LoginResponse&scope=https://graph.windows.net/Directory.AccessAsUser.All
>   https://graph.windows.net/User.Read&response_type=code&prompt=login

The call to token endpoint is as shown below:

> HTTP POST to URL: https://{my tenant}.b2clogin.com/{my
>   tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signinsignup/oauth2/v2.0/token Content
>   type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body:

> grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={my app
>   id}&scope=https://graph.windows.net/Directory.AccessAsUser.All
>   https://graph.windows.net/User.Read&code={the code received from
>   authorize
>   endpoint}&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44351/Login/LoginResponse&client_secret={secret from the portal}

The HTTP POST to token endpoint is successful. I get the JWT token, and I am able to successfully retrieve the access token from the JWT. However, when I try to use this access token to retrieve the user details, the below code fails every time with 401 response. The error message is

> "odata.error":{"code":"Authentication_ExpiredToken","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Your
>   access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the
>   request."}}}"

```
string strURL = @"https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6";
                HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL);
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {jWTToken.access_token}");                
                using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string str = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
```

The JWT token used in the above code is the one I receive from the Token endpoint. Why is it failing? The access token I received is decoded by jwt.ms as follows:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "X5eXk4xyojNFum1kl2Ytv8dlNP4-c57dO6QGTVBwaNk"
}.{
  "iss": "https://{my tenant}.b2clogin.com/fc292353-4def-47bd-af44-b92e40798a60/v2.0/",
  "exp": 1576642155,
  "nbf": 1576638555,
  "aud": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "oid": "05c93456-2f02-4601-afb0-d4599b7e6826",
  "sub": "05c93456-2f02-4601-afb0-d4599b7e6826",
  "tfp": "B2C_1_signinsignup",
  "nonce": "defaultNonce",
  "scp": "Directory.AccessAsUser.All User.Read",
  "azp": "{my app ID}",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "iat": 1576638555
}.[Signature]
```

Answer (score 3):

B2C does not support delegated access to Graph API.
You have to add *Application permissions* to the app registration,
and use client credential authentication to get tokens.

See docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet?tabs=applications#assign-api-access-permissions

> Under APPLICATION PERMISSIONS, select Read and write directory data.

Acquire the tokens from the underlying Azure AD's token endpoint, not your B2C policy endpoint.

You won't be able to use `/me` of course since the token won't contain user info.
But you can use `/users/id` instead.

The reason for the 401 is probably the issuer in your token.
Graph API expects the normal AAD issuer, and that is not it.

Comment: Where I will get the id parameter from?

Comment: You can either get it from a token when the user has signed in, or you can search for specific users with filters via /users.

Comment: How can I get the token? I have a web app that is under aad, And I want to get the signed in user's details.That's what I do: var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.windows.net/me/manager?api-version=1.6");
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken); And I get Resource not found for the segment 'me'. Do you have any idea? Thank's