# Do you have to sign out and sign back in to a web app that uses Azure B2C authentication to get updated user data?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

According to [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/tree/main/1-Authentication/2-sign-in-b2c#running-the-sample:%7E:text=Like%20password%20reset%2C%20edit%20profile%20user%2Dflow%20requires%20users%20to%20sign%2Dout%20and%20sign%2Din%20again.), you have to sign out and sign back into the web app to see the changes you just made to your B2C account with the edit profile flow. Is there a way around this, because this seems like very bad UX. I've thought of using the graph API to fetch the signed-in user's data after returning from the edit profile flow, but using the graph api with b2c seems complicated.

- For one, it doesn't seem that you can get a dedicated access token to the graph api from b2c sign-up/sign-in - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59385243/azure-ad-b2c-graph-api-401-unauthorized?rq=1#:%7E:text=B2C%20does%20not%20support%20delegated%20access%20to%20Graph%20API.%20You%20have%20to%20add%20Application%20permissions%20to%20the%20app%20registration%2C%20and%20use%20client%20credential%20authentication%20to%20get%20tokens.). You can only allow application permissions for the graph api which I'd assume aren't secure, seeing as users would then be able to mess with other users' data and not just their own.
- Another solution is to use function apps to call the graph api (see [this](https://techmindfactory.com/Modern-Identity-Platform-On-Azure/#:%7E:text=Solution%20architecture%20diagram)), but that seems overly-complicated and would cost extra.
- I've also ran across having a web api as a proxy that just checks which user is calling it and then determines if they have access to the requested endpoint - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73587445/what-is-the-best-way-to-obtain-a-microsoft-graph-api-token-through-an-azure-b2c#:%7E:text=Is%20the%20proper%20way%20to%20do%20this%20is%20to%20build%20a%20proxy%20that%20will%20take%20the%20application%27s%20AD%20application%20permissions%20which%20are%20allowed%20to%20call%20out%20to%20Microsoft%20Graph%20and%20pass%20along%20user%20context%20so%20that%20the%20scope%20will%20be%20limited%20to%20that%20user%20only%3F).
- I've also been recommended to use an api like the previous solution, but use an API connector to call it - see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1055129/how-to-perform-crud-operations-for-azure-b2c-users.html#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20update%20any%20user%20profile%2C%20you%20may%20create%20a%20custom%20API%20that%20calls%20the%20MS%20Graph%20as%20an%20application%20and%20consume%20it%20through%20an%20API%20connector.). However, the API connectors seem to only be able to be invoked during sign-up and sign-in processes, not just on demand whenever the logged in user wants - see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/api-connectors-overview?pivots=b2c-user-flow).

My desired end result is to have users be able to login, edit their profile, and view those changes on the web app without having to sign out and sign back in.

I'm fairly confident being able to assign delegated permissions for ms graph from the app registration would solve this, so if you know why it is that we can't assign delegated permissions for ms graph api with azure b2c, I'd be curious to know why. I would have thought that would be something you could do.

I've looked into other CIAM solutions and Firebase and Auth0 seem popular and may solve these issues, but Azure B2C seems cheaper at $0.00325/MAU vs Firebase's $0.0055/MAU which is why I'd like to figure out if there's ways around these apparent B2C limitations. If you have any authentication suggestions, I'm open to them.

**TLDR**

- Is it possible with Azure B2C to allow a signed-in user to run through the edit profile flow without having to sign out and sign back in to see the changes?

I've ran the sample found [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/tree/main/1-Authentication/2-sign-in-b2c#running-the-sample) to confirm the behavior of having to sign out and sign back in.

Answer (score 1):

When the user goes to view their profile information, have the application make a call to your B2C tenant's userinfo endpoint to get up to date information from B2C. Documentation on setting this up can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userinfo-endpoint?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).